# Google has replaced page title and not showing page content. Any idea why?

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense, pagerank, title

This week i tried to upgrade my site to https and i also changed the homepage title from "Home" to "Tech Reviews And Tutorials". My page is https://getgeek.net. After these changes google has dropped my ranking but also changed what it has picked up from my page. For example the title of the page should be "GetGeek.Net - Tech reviews and tutorials" but has been replaced with a load of Asian symbols. This is also the same for the first line of the description but i have written no Asian content on my site.

You can see the page here:
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=getgeek&start=10

I think the other day AdSense was showing an Asian advert, is it possible that this is what google picked up?

Does anyone know why it has done this and if there is anyway to revert it back?

Thanks

Comment: This can happen normally because of two things, DNS issues or a Hack. Sometimes if the host temporarily points to the wrong server then it can prompt Google to think your site has been moved. The other is a hacked site. 


You can clear see this is the case by viewing Google's cache on your site (https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AFaLX6QcaU8J:https://getgeek.net/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-b. So this isn't a Google issue... something is up with your site. Based on the information provided its impossible for users to tell the issue without speculating.

Comment: Currently the question is considered off-topic because its 'This is my site' what is the problem type question which is unlikely to help others. In additional to this as mentioned above the question is impossible to answer with the information provided without guessing (another hold reason).